# Batch File move files base on last characters of their name

Tags: batch-file, directory, move

Is it possible for a bat file to search for folders and files and
if it finds file named as part of a folder name to move that file into that folder.

For example:

```
D:\
└───Test
    │   161136.pdf
    │   23752.pdf
    │   24334.pd
    │
    ├───017-161136
    ├───021-23752
    ├───120-24334
    └───1560-4334
```

The name of the files are 4 to 6 characters and the folders are made to contain the files name.

Expected result

```
D:\
└───Test
    ├───017-161136
    │       161136.pdf
    │
    ├───021-23752
    │       23752.pdf
    │
    ├───120-24334
    │       24334.pdf
    │
    └───1560-4334
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). **BTW**, it's possible however you could do such a task more  easy using  _PowerShell_..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much difference using either PowerShell

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\14\SO_56599031.ps1
PushD D:\Test
Get-ChildItem *-* -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item ("{1}*" -f ($_.Name.split('-')[1])) -Dest $_.Name -WhatIf
}
PopD
```

or batch to solve the task

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\06\14\SO_56599031.cmd
@Echo off
Pushd D:\Test
for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%A in ('Dir /B /AD *-*') do (
  move "%%~B*" "%%A-%%B"
)
PopD
```